# Add ipv4 support to CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, virtualbox, ipv6, ipv4

I've installed two identical versions of CentOS using VirtualBox. The first instance works fine and has ipv4 configuration automatically working, but the second instance doesn't; it only comes with ipv6 and no ipv4. How can I manually add ipv4 support?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and see if `NETWORK=yes` is set on the machine without ipv4. That is normally what turns on netowrking if the appropriate packages are installed.

if it is missing add it and `run service network restart` . 
I think that will help.

See `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.03.31` for docco.